# How deployment downtime maintenance page enabled/disabled for React APP in azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, environment-variables, azure-appservice

I want to enable/disable maintenance page for my react application in Azure without deployment.

Approach followed:
added one variable in .env file (REACT_APP_IS_MAINTENANCE_PAGE_ENABLED= 0) and same key in App settings of Environment variables in azure App, but unable to read value from environment variable from Azure App service.
How can we achieve this?

please suggest any other approaches if this won't work.

Comment: Can you share more details with the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have manually added a toggle button between the maintenance page and regular content without fetching from an external source. It worked locally and in the Azure web app.

**Code :**

***src/components/App.js :***

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MaintenancePage from './MaintenancePage';

const App = () => {
  const [isMaintenancePageEnabled, setIsMaintenancePageEnabled] = useState(false);

  const toggleMaintenancePage = () => {
    setIsMaintenancePageEnabled(!isMaintenancePageEnabled);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleMaintenancePage}>
        Toggle Maintenance Page ({isMaintenancePageEnabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'})
      </button>
      {isMaintenancePageEnabled ? (
        <MaintenancePage />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome to the App!</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**src/components/maintenancePage.js :**

```js
import React from 'react';

const MaintenancePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Maintenance Page</h1>
      <p>Sorry, we are currently undergoing maintenance. Please check back later.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MaintenancePage;
```

**Output :**

I was able to **build** and **run** the react app successfully using below commands,

> **npm run build**
>
> **npm start**

[image]
[image]

I got the below output with the port **3000**. Then, I clicked on **Toggle Maintenance Page(Disabled)** to get the maintenance page as below,

[image]

I could enable and disable the maintenance page using the below **toggle button** as below,

[image]

Then, I deployed my **build folder** to **Azure web app** as below,

[image]

I could **enable and disable the maintenance page** using the toggle button** in the Azure web app below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not good to show Toggle Button in UI. any other way like by using  environment variables in App service.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using Deployment Slots.
Steps followed:

- New Deployment Slot created and deployed maintenance Page.
- Changing deployment slot Traffic% Percentage to 100%, whenever down
  time is required.

[image]